# vba Header in Excel 2010 that includes the Creation Date as well as the Last Updated Date

Tags: excel, vba, date, header

I need to create a header in Excel 2010 that contains the Creation Date as well as the Last Saved Date.  Here is what I have so far.  What I need is the piece that will put the Creation Date in (indicated by the THIS IS WHAT I NEED HELP WITH below.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, _
        Cancel As Boolean)

    Cancel = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = "Date Created " & THIS IS WHAT I NEED HELP WITH
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = "Last Update " & Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: .LeftHeader = "Date Created " & thisworkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties(11)